# ListFragment и commit

Tags: android

Создаю несколько списков на основе ListFragment и ArrayAdapter.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class List extends ListFragment
{
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> mArrayAdapter1, mArrayAdapter2, mArrayAdapter3;
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mArrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array1));
        mFragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        mArrayAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
        setListAdapter(mArrayAdapter1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        if (getListAdapter() == mArrayAdapter1) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    mArrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array2));
                    setListAdapter(mArrayAdapter2);
                    mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    mArrayAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    break;
            }
        } else if (getListAdapter() == mArrayAdapter2) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    mArrayAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array3));
                    setListAdapter(mArrayAdapter3);
                    mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    mArrayAdapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    break;
            }
        }
        mFragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

При нажатии на пункт одного списка, открывается другой. Из второго списка открывается третий и т. д. Однако при переходе с одного списка к другому (при нажатии на пункт списка) приложение аварийно завершается и Android Studio выдаёт ошибки:

```
01-04 22:14:32.956 4637-4637/com.test.example E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.test.example, PID: 4637
java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called

at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:621)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:613)
at com.test.example.List.onListItemClick(List.java:58)
at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:58)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:308)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1510)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3472)
at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4835)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Я новичок по фрагментам, поэтому очень прошу помочь мне понять и решить проблему. Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вы не можете коммитить одну FragmentTransaction несколько раз. Из за этого и вылетает ошибка.
2. Зачем вам вообще FragmentTransaction если вы в неё никакие манипуляции с фрагментами не помещаете? FragmentTransaction нужно что бы добавлять, удалять или заменять фрагменты, у Вас же всё происходит в одном фрагменте.

Удалите всю работу с FragmentTransaction и всё должно заработать:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class List extends ListFragment {
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> mArrayAdapter1, mArrayAdapter2, mArrayAdapter3;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mArrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array1));
        mArrayAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
        setListAdapter(mArrayAdapter1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        if (getListAdapter() == mArrayAdapter1) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    mArrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array2));
                    setListAdapter(mArrayAdapter2);
                    mArrayAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    break;
            }
        } else if (getListAdapter() == mArrayAdapter2) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    mArrayAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array3));
                    setListAdapter(mArrayAdapter3);
                    mArrayAdapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Если хотите сохранять списки в бэкстеке фрагментов, то надо для каждого списка создавать новый фрагмент, как то так:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class List extends ListFragment {
    private static final String ADAPTER_NUM_KEY = "ADAPTER_NUM_KEY";

    private ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> mArrayAdapter;
    private int adapterNum = 1;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            adapterNum = getArguments().getInt(ADAPTER_NUM_KEY, 1);
        }
        int arrayId;
        switch (adapterNum) {
            case 1:
            default:
                arrayId = R.array.array1;
                break;
            case 2:
                arrayId = R.array.array2;
                break;
            case 3:
                arrayId = R.array.array3;
                break;
        }
        mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(arrayId));
        setListAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        if (adapterNum == 1) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    showNewList(2);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    break;
            }
        } else if (adapterNum == 2) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    showNewList(3);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void showNewList(int adapterNum) {
        Fragment fragment = new List();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ADAPTER_NUM_KEY, adapterNum);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.YOUR_FRAGMENT_CONTAINER_ID, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

YOUR_FRAGMENT_CONTAINER_ID - id вашего контейнера для фрагмента в лэйауте активити.

Comment: 1. Commit использовался только один раз, в конце метода OnListItemClick.
2. FragmentTransaction нужен для addToBackStack(). Возможно ли заменить эту функцию, чтобы при нажатии кнопки "назад" открывался предыдущий список?
3. От всей души благодарю за ответ.

Comment: А onListItemClick по вашему только один раз может вызваться? Если бы вы транзакцию и создавали и коммитили в onListItemClick, то вопросов бы не было. Далее, addToBackStack() сохраняет только действия над транзакцией, то есть add, attach, detach, replace, и т.д. О вашем списке и адаптере он ничего знать не знает и сохранять никуда не будет. Хотите сделать действие по нажатию кнопки назад - прокиньте во фрагмент вызов onBackPressed из активити и делайте там что вам нужно, но стек списков вам придется самому создавать.

Comment: Дополнил ответ вариантом с созданием отдельного фрагмента для каждого списка. В таком виде можно использовать бэкстек FragmentManager'а.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за разъяснения, буду разбираться